# Nginx Server Configuration: Hostname not resolving on Subdomain

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

thank you in advance for your support.

I set up an Ubuntu Server with Nginx as a Digitalocean Droplet and am using the server provisioning tool **Laravel Forge**, which works fine. I successfully installed the PHP Framework Laravel and deployed the code on the server. I ssh into the server and checked the files in the supposed directory. The code is successfully deployed.

Next I own a domain, and created an A record for the following subdomain: **app.mywebsite.de**, that points to that server. I followed the [digitalocean instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/dns/how-to/add-subdomain/) and I waited the required time. Using a DNS Lookup tool, I confirmed that the subdomain actually points to the server.

[Screenshot of DNS Lookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEaL8.png)

Yet, when I use the subdomain in my browser, the browser doesn't connect to the server. I get the following error message in the browser:

[Screenshot of Browser when connecting to server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O06RR.png)

It seems like the subdomain is correctly pointed to the server, but the server isn't rightly configured. I tried to check the nginx configuration and under *sites-avaialble* I have the following configuration for the subdomain:

```
    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/app.mywebsite.de/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name app.mywebsite.de;
    server_tokens off;
    root /home/forge/app.mywebsite.de/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers TLS13-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS13-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/app.mywebsite.de/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/app.mywebsite.de-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/app.mywebsite.de/after/*;
```

In **forge-conf/app.website.de/before/*;** is only one file **redirect.conf** with the following code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.app.website.de;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'https') {
        return 301 https://app.website.de$request_uri;
    }

    return 301 $scheme://app.website.de$request_uri;
}
```

There are no other sites on the server. So there is only the **000-catch-all** file in the **sites available** directory of the nginx configuration folder.

Unfortunately I reached my limit of understanding here and I would love if somebody could point me into the right direction to find out, which part of nginx is not configured corectly.

P.S.
Some additional info:
Yes I restarted Nginx and the whole server multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, everything was configured correctly. I didn't change anything, except that I added some additional sites on the nginx server. Forge probably updated the server blocks, which resolved the problem.